# Ionic - iOS - Store the Path to file in Photo library

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, path, filesystems

Working on Ionic app, I’m trying to store and reuse a path to video in the iOS photo library. Using the Ionic-native camera plugin. However, each time I open a video, it generates and provides a new path with new uuid in **tmp** folder. Xcode log example:

```
2018-06-06 16:10:11.062523+0800 openGallery >> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B3C0CDB7-6B2D-4F32-8C0C-632AE0D8FC79/tmp/BFDDB5BC-7F0B-42E5-B943-E5F9EAF25FB5.MOV
2018-06-06 16:10:11.062655+0800 file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B3C0CDB7-6B2D-4F32-8C0C-632AE0D8FC79/tmp/BFDDB5BC-7F0B-42E5-B943-E5F9EAF25FB5.MOV
```

Here is my code:

```
  openGallery() {
console.log('open gallery');
let cameraOptions = {
  mediaType: MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
  sourceType: PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  destinationType: DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
  quality: 100,
  targetWidth: 600,
  targetHeight: 600,
  encodingType: EncodingType.JPEG,
  correctOrientation: true
}

return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions)
    .then(file_uri => {
      if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        file_uri = "file://" + file_uri;
      }
      console.log("openGallery >> " + file_uri)
      resolve(file_uri);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err)
      reject(err)
    });
})
```

Is there any way to store a path to existing video in library without making a copy in the app folder?